# Adding a column with default value of the date of the day after tomorrow

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using Mysql Workbench for my Database class in college, and even tho it's pretty simple to use, there're some things I just can't work around.

Right now, I'm stuck with trying to model a Blockbuster-like store. on my Rentals page, I want to add an Exp_Ret_Date, Act_Ret_Date and Book_Date. Now, Book_Date and Exp_Ret_Date have both default values: Book_Date's is NOW(), and Exp_Ret_Date is supposed to be 2 days after Book_Date.

So, I tried to write DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) on the Default camp, but it just doesn't work. I tried using TIMESTAMP, CURDATE, ADDDATE, and anything else I could think of, but it did no good. So, if anyone could orient me as to what I could do to fix this, me and my classmates would be really greatfull.

Here's the whole code generated by MySQL Workbench. It kept saying there is a syntax error in the line with DATE_ADD part.

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`MEMBER`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`MEMBER` (
  `MEMBER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  `FIRST_NAME` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
  `ADDRESS` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `CITY` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `PHONE` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `JOIN_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`MEMBER_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `MEMBER_ID_UNIQUE` (`MEMBER_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TITLE`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TITLE` (
  `TITLE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `TITLE` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(400) NOT NULL,
  `RATING` ENUM('G','PG','R','NC17','NR') NULL,
  `CATEGORY` ENUM('DRAMA','COMEDY','ACTION','CHILD','SCIFI','DOCUMENTARY') NULL,
  `RELEASE_DATE` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TITLE_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `TITLE_ID_UNIQUE` (`TITLE_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`TITLE_COPY`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TITLE_COPY` (
  `COPY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` ENUM('AVAILIBLE','DESTROYED','RENTED','RESERVED') NOT NULL,
  `TITLE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`COPY_ID`, `TITLE_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `COPY_ID_UNIQUE` (`COPY_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_TITLE_COPY_TITLE_idx` (`TITLE_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TITLE_COPY_TITLE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TITLE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TITLE` (`TITLE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`RENTAL`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`RENTAL` (
  `BOOK_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `ACT_RET_DATE` DATETIME NULL,
  `EXP_RET_DATE` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY,
  `MEMBER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `COPY_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `TITLE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BOOK_DATE`, `COPY_ID`, `TITLE_ID`, `MEMBER_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `BOOK_DATE_UNIQUE` (`BOOK_DATE` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_RENTAL_MEMBER1_idx` (`MEMBER_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_RENTAL_TITLE_COPY1_idx` (`COPY_ID` ASC, `TITLE_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RENTAL_MEMBER1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`MEMBER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MEMBER` (`MEMBER_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RENTAL_TITLE_COPY1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`COPY_ID` , `TITLE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TITLE_COPY` (`COPY_ID` , `TITLE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`RESERVATION`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`RESERVATION` (
  `RES_DATE` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `MEMBER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `TITLE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RES_DATE`, `MEMBER_ID`, `TITLE_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_RESERVATION_MEMBER1_idx` (`MEMBER_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_RESERVATION_TITLE1_idx` (`TITLE_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RESERVATION_MEMBER1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`MEMBER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`MEMBER` (`MEMBER_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RESERVATION_TITLE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TITLE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`TITLE` (`TITLE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Error is around line 72.

Comment: `DEFAULT` can't be an expression, it has to be a literal (or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a special exception). If you want to fill in fields with a computed value automatically, use a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The `UNIQUE INDEX` definitions are redundant, most of those aren't needed.

For example, `MEMBER_ID` is already defined as the `PRIMARY KEY`; a second unique index with that column as the leading column isn't really necessary.

```
PRIMARY KEY (`MEMBER_ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `MEMBER_ID_UNIQUE` (`MEMBER_ID` ASC))
```

I can understand that InnoDB doesn't throw an exception; some queries might be able to make use of a "narrow" index, but it would be a rare use case where this second index actually improves performance. Same thing applies here:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`TITLE_ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `TITLE_ID_UNIQUE` (`TITLE_ID` ASC))
```

The `UNIQUE INDEX` is redundant, since `TITLE_ID` is already defined as the unique cluster key for the table.

And this is a bit bizarre, `COPY_ID` is unique, but the `PRIMARY KEY` is defined to be the combination of that unique column, and a second column:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`COPY_ID`, `TITLE_ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `COPY_ID_UNIQUE` (`COPY_ID` ASC),
```

It would be sufficient to just make `COPY_ID` the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table. Same applies to this...

```
PRIMARY KEY (`BOOK_DATE`, `COPY_ID`, `TITLE_ID`, `MEMBER_ID`),
UNIQUE INDEX `BOOK_DATE_UNIQUE` (`BOOK_DATE` ASC),
```

But in this case, I suspect that `BOOK_DATE` is not actually unique. If it is, there's no need for a composite primary key.

---

To have the database automatically assign a value to a column when a row is inserted, you could define a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger. (As Barmar noted in his comment, MySQL is limited in what it accepts as a DEFAULT value... it has to be a *literal* value, it can't be an expression.  (With one small exception for the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for `TIMESTAMP` columns; used to be you could only do that on columns of datatype `TIMESTAMP`, but I think more recent version of MySQL supports something similar for `DATETIME columns.)

As a simple example of a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER mytable_bi 
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.exp_ret_date = NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger will override any value that is supplied. You could perform a conditional test in the trigger, to check whether the column value is NULL, before assigning a value to it:

```
  IF NEW.exp_ret_date IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.exp_ret_date = NOW() + INTERVAL 2 DAY;
  END IF;
```