# current_timestamp interval 4 day in into or other expression

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause, sql-insert

Hello im haveing this code and i want to add data in the table also the current day +4 day interval, i tried with the beginig of the table creation dident work or i need an expresion thas gonna change the date value to the current_timestamp interval 4 day.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Spital`.`Stoc General` (
  `ID Produs` INT ,
  `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantitate` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID Produs`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Select*From `Spital`.`Stoc General`;
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) VALUES ('1', 'Clabax', '20');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) VALUES ('2', 'Betadina', '15');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) VALUES ('3', 'Paracetamo', '4');
INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc general` (`ID Produs`, `Denumire`, `Cantitate`) VALUES ('4', 'Oxigen', '3');


CREATE TABLE if not exists `Spital`.`Stoc URGENT` (
  `ID Produs U` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id produs` int not null,
  `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantitate` INT NOT NULL,
   `Data livrari` DATETIME On update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID Produs U`))
ENGINE = MEMORY;

INSERT INTO `spital`.`stoc urgent`
            (`id produs`,
             `denumire`,
             `cantitate`)
SELECT `id produs`,
       `denumire`,
       `cantitate`
FROM   `spital`.`stoc general` 
where  `cantitate`<'5';
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking but perhaps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL add days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820322/mysql-add-days-to-a-date)

Comment: i need to int the date of current day with the interval of 4 day in this syntax or other separately  into Stoc Urgent

Comment: Now i put all the code

Comment: @P.Salmon on the data livrari i need this `code` (Current_timestamp(), interval 4 day) `code` but it dident work when i wanted to put it into the creation of the table

Comment: i think you need to create a trigger (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620993/724039 ) because the `on update` only allows current_timestamp().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the value during the insertion, so you must set `DEFAULT` column's option:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists `Spital`.`Stoc URGENT` (
  `ID Produs U` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id produs` int not null,
  `Denumire` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cantitate` INT NOT NULL,
   `Data livrari` DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 4 DAY)
                           On update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID Produs U`))
ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

1. Parenthesis around the expression are compulsory.
2. You cannot set the same expression in ON UPDATE option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that it would be better to create StockUrgent as a view than as a new table. There is not point in storing duplicate values.
I have also taken the liberty of removing the spaces in the table and column name. This avoids the need to surround all the names with backticks and speeds up writing the queries.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS StockGeneral (
> IdProdus INT ,
>   Denumire VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
>   Cantitate DATE NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (IdProdus));
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO StockGeneral  VALUES ('1', 'Clabax', '2022-03-20');
> INSERT INTO StockGeneral  VALUES ('2', 'Betadina', '2022-03-15');
> INSERT INTO  StockGeneral  VALUES ('3', 'Paracetamo', '2022-03-24');
> INSERT INTO  StockGeneral  VALUES ('4', 'Oxigen', '2022-03-30');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   idProdus,
>   Denumire,
>   cantitate,
>   DateDiff(cantitate,current_date())
> FROM StockGeneral
> ```
>
> ```
> idProdus | Denumire   | cantitate  | DateDiff(cantitate,current_date())
> -------: | :--------- | :--------- | ---------------------------------:
>        1 | Clabax     | 2022-03-20 |                                  4
>        2 | Betadina   | 2022-03-15 |                                 -1
>        3 | Paracetamo | 2022-03-24 |                                  8
>        4 | Oxigen     | 2022-03-30 |                                 14
> ```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW StockUrgent AS
> SELECT 
>   idProdus,
>   Denumire,
>   cantitate
> FROM StockGeneral
> WHERE DateDiff(cantitate,current_date())< 5;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM StockUrgent;
> ```
>
> ```
> idProdus | Denumire | cantitate 
> -------: | :------- | :---------
>        1 | Clabax   | 2022-03-20
>        2 | Betadina | 2022-03-15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=048b11dcf3ac7102a91ef9cbc11cb727)*

Comment: I changed the code befor for not haveing duplicate values and i used the view creation like you said and the backticks for being more easy to read cuz this is an project and is gonna be better like this